# Making EditText in android 2.3 to look like as in android higher versions

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an android app in version 2.3. I need to create a editTex that has the same effect as the EditText coast "from" image

[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

Comment: What's exact problem?You can set image as background to edittext

Comment: There are lot's edittext in image, which one you want?

Comment: use drawable for right side

Comment: It looks like a spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like below.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile_one"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Tap to enter title"
        android:gravity="top|left" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

This line `android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile_one"` will set the image in your edit-text so just replace `profile_one` this name with your image name.

Like wise you can set image to left, right, and bottom also with following property.

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/profile_one"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile_one"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/profile_one"
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set image as background to EditText

Answer (score 0):

You can use nine patch image for the background image of edittext.

Are you luking for spinner more specifically custom spinner

Try custom spinner and create edit text as a custom view that It is to be inflate an image.

Refer following link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nine patch if its only an image back-ground.

So Create a [nine patch image](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) that looks like the one you want and apply it as a background to your EditText.

```
android:background="your image";
```

To me it appears more like a spinner though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not agree with either of any other answers, but you could use [**HoloEveryWhere**](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) to provide a compatibility and make your EditText looks similar in all the versions.

[image]